# Python function calling logics

Tags: python, function

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I have just started learning Python. I agree the below snippet does not work before the definition is not written before calling it.

```
repeat()

def print_lyrics():
    print('hi')
    print('hello')

def repeat():
    print_lyrics()
    print_lyrics()
```

However, if i change the order of print_lyrics() and repeat(), it still works.

```
 def repeat():
    print_lyrics()
    print_lyrics()

 def print_lyrics():
    print('hi')
    print('hello')

 repeat()
```

Does it not expect us to be in order same as above since repeat() calls print_lyrics(). I m just trying to understand how this works (or) scans this internally(during run time?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what order you define a set of functions in, as long as all of the functions that are called have been defined before they are called.

In your example, no function calls are executed at the time the functions are defined.  It isn't until the invocation of `repeat()` that the first function call is actually made.  At that time, `repeat` must be defined, as well as all of the functions that it calls, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: +1 a good example of how this applies is if the `repeat` call is placed between the two definitions as at that time `repeat` has been defined but still fails as `print_lyrics` hasn't.

Comment: Tom Karzes, thank you so much and @NickA thats awesome, made it clear.